# Display dates in ISO 8601 format in the Microsoft Outlook web interface

Tags: outlook.com, date

Is it possible to display the dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

I read on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Time-zone-and-language-settings-in-Outlook-Web-App-5565cc28-bc5c-47f1-849d-b57f1ffdfb53:

[image]

However I cannot find the `options` menu. Screenshot from my web interface:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to click on the setting button (the wheel) right when the page is loading, before your name appears on the top right. If you do so, then the setting menu has many more entries, including `options`:

[image]

Then you can change the date format:

[image]